# Excute SELECT after CREATE in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, select-into

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL, although I have a lot of experience with SQL.
At the moment I am trying to convert a couple of T-SQL statements to PL/SQL. I am trying to execute the following code, but I get some errors.

If the table does not exist yet, then the error is: Table or view does not exist.
But when I run the query without the second select statement it creates the table. Now that the table exists I tried to execute it once more and now I am getting the following error:

> An INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.

The code I am using:

```
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER;
  stmt VARCHAR2(1000) := 'CREATE TABLE LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE (LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE TIMESTAMP NULL)';
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE';

    IF (cnt = 0) THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
    END IF;

    SELECT COALESCE((
      SELECT LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE WHERE ROWNUM = 1
      ), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM dual;
END;
```

How can I solve this...?

Comment: Well yeah your second select is returning a value and you are not doing anything with it. What would you like to do with the LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE retuned? Just do the same thing that you did with the "select count(*) into" and your code will work, you can then decide what to do with that value.

Comment: Coalesce function is returns first not null value so for holding that value in oracle we need a variable like select coalesce(var1,var2) into var3 from table _name. Now var3 contains either var1 or var2.

Comment: When table does not exist the pre-compiler sees you are referencing an object in second select that does not exist at compile time (LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE)

Comment: @Robert: I understand that. Therefore I try to check for the existence of the table and if not create it.

Comment: @user2782991 The PL/SQL compiler does not see that you will create the table if it does not exist. At compile time you're referencing a table that does not exist and will always return a compiler error. You will have to convert the select to dynamic sql too if you want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER;
  stmt VARCHAR2(1000) := 'CREATE TABLE LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE (LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE TIMESTAMP NULL)';
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE';

IF (cnt = 0) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
END IF;

SELECT COALESCE((
  SELECT LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE WHERE ROWNUM = 1
  ), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM dual;
END;
```

To:

```
DECLARE
  V_LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE varchar2(100);
  cnt NUMBER;
  stmt VARCHAR2(1000) := 'CREATE TABLE LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE (LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE TIMESTAMP NULL)';
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE';

IF (cnt = 0) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
END IF;

SELECT COALESCE((
  SELECT LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE 
    FROM LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE 
   WHERE ROWNUM = 1), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 
    INTO V_LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE 
    FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: The procedure executes now, but how do you get the results out of that variable? I tried to use dbms_output.put_line(V_LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE). Unfortunately no success... Actually it needs to end up in a .NET application.

Comment: What you have right now is just an anonymous block, not a procedure. You want to put in the first line: "Create or replace procedure PROCEDURE_NAME (v_out_LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE as varchar2) AS". Then at the end just add another "end;" statement. Now this will build the procedure which will return you a variable of your choosing when you add the line "return V_LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE". I don't know how PLSQL procedure calls work in .NET though. Also if you want dbms_output.put_line to work you need to "set serveroutput on;" in your terminal or whichever tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

your second query needs the INTO statement

```
SELECT COALESCE((
      SELECT LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE WHERE ROWNUM = 1
      ), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE 
INTO l_someVariable 
FROM dual;
```

remember to declare the `l_someVariable`  in the `DECLARE` section

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT COALESCE((
>         SELECT LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE WHERE ROWNUM = 1
>         ), TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS LAST_LOG_ARCHIVE FROM dual;

**PL/SQL** is different from **SQL**. You must use **INTO** clause, as a SELECT statement without INTO clause would fail in PL/SQL. Basically, it makes no sense to select a row and do nothing about it.

If  you just want to do the select then do it in pure SQL and not in PL/SQL. If you want to store the respective values from the row returned by the select into local variables, then use **INTO** clause.

```
SELECT col1, col2 INTO var1, var2 FROM table
```

Declare the variables `var1` and `var2` with respective **datatype** of the columns in the select list.

Read more about [SELECT INTO Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) from documentation.

Also,

> TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

You could simply use **TO_DATE** instead of **TO_TIMESTAMP**. A Date has both date and time elements.

```
TO_DATE('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```